# Apache Drill query retrieving data older than 6 months

Tags: apache-drill

Hello im new in Apache Drill and i'm trying to do something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM `dfs`.`data`.`./bp2s/nt/raw/20220909/16_09_34_1665670176715.NTFF04_FFMA_20220909_Positions_20220909181421268120.txt.parquet` Where VALUATION_DATE "older than 6 months"
```

Any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select ... where valuation_date < current_date - interval '6' month;
```

The inequality in the WHERE clause compares the `valuation_date` column to an expression that subtracts 6 months from today's date thereby including only those records that have a valuation_date ealier than 6 months ago.

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.

Comment: @Lee Goddard what would I add beyond the explanatory paragraph already present in the answer?

Comment: looking at the dates/times on the edit history and the date/time on my comment, it seems you added the requested explanation, thanks. A reference to documentation is also always appreciated! Have a good day.